# How to style react-popper using render props in class components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, popper.js, react-popper

Just updated to `react-popper 2.3.0` and `@popperjs/core: "2.11.6`
Tring to set the style as desribed on [it's own doc](https://popper.js.org/react-popper/v2/render-props/), but writing:   `<Popper children={({style:{color:'red'}}) => <div>opened</div>} strategy="fixed" />` returns the error `Property 'red' does not exist on type 'CSSProperties'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a string literal type to specify the property value, like this:

```
<Popper children={({style:{color:'red' as 'red'}}) => <div>opened</div>} strategy="fixed" />
```

This will tell `TypeScript` that the value of "color" is the string literal "red", which is a valid CSS color value.